# How can I create a function in zsh that calls an existing command with the same name?

Tags: zsh, function

How can I write a function in `zsh` that invokes an existing command with the same name as the function itself? For example, I've tried this to illustrate my question:

```
function ls 
{
    ls -l $1 $2 $3
}
```

When I execute it with `ls *` I get the following:

```
ls:1: maximum nested function level reached
```

I assume this is because the function is being called recursively. How I can avoid that?

This is a crude example, and in this case an alias would do the job, but I have a more complex example where an alias isn't suitable and so I would need to write a function.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What is happening is that you are recursively calling your `ls` function. In order to use the binary, you can use ZSH's `command` builtin.

```
function ls {
    command ls -l "$@"
}
```