# Best way to call command within a shell function having the same name

Tags: shell, command, function

I like to encapsulate commands within shell-functions using the same name. But to avoid the shell-function calling itself recursively, I specify the complete path of the command as the following example:

```
less()
{
    test 0 -lt $# && echo -ne "\e]2;$@\a\e]1;$@\a"     # Window title
    /usr/bin/less -i -rS --LONG-PROMPT --shift 5 "$@"
}
```

But for some commands, I do not want to specify the path because it may change. I would prefer to use `$PATH`.

For instance, my following attempt failed to call `mvn` command using backslash: `\mvn`

```
mvn()  # colorizes maven output
{
        \mvn "$@" 2>&1 | #here: the shell-function recursively calls itself indefinitely
        sed -u '                                             
    s/^\[ALL\].*/\o033[1;37m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[FATAL\].*/\o033[1;31m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[ERROR\].*/\o033[1;31m&\o033[0m/
s/^\[WARNING\].*/\o033[1;33m&\o033[0m/
   s/^\[INFO\].*/\o033[1;37m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[DEBUG\].*/\o033[1;36m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[TRACE\].*/\o033[1;32m&\o033[0m/'
}
```

**What is the best way to bypass this issue?** 
 
Please do not suggest to use a different shell-function name.

(I usually use `bash` but I am interested about other shell solutions.)

Comment: `zsh` answer, but applies for `bash` too: [How can I create a function in zsh that calls an existing command with the same name?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65897/how-can-i-create-a-function-in-zsh-that-calls-an-existing-command-with-the-same).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prepend your actual commands (not functions) with `command` shell builtin, it has exactly the purpose you're looking for. Therefore your shell-function should look that:

```
mvn()
{
        command mvn "$@" 2>&1 |
        sed -u '
    s/^\[ALL\].*/\o033[1;37m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[FATAL\].*/\o033[1;31m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[ERROR\].*/\o033[1;31m&\o033[0m/
s/^\[WARNING\].*/\o033[1;33m&\o033[0m/
   s/^\[INFO\].*/\o033[1;37m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[DEBUG\].*/\o033[1;36m&\o033[0m/
  s/^\[TRACE\].*/\o033[1;32m&\o033[0m/'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what shell you use.  By default zfs, bash and ksh does not expand aliases with the same name as the alias, in aliases.  This is specifically to avoid [usually unintentional] loops.

Therefore you are safe to make commands like you want to do.

```
alias ls="echo Hello; ls"
```

Is perfectly fine.

Comment: The question was about function, not alias.

Comment: Note that adding the full path to the command inside the alias sometimes gives a benefit in that that command will run without having to search the PATH!!!